# AAD Graph API returns 404 after call to AcquireTokenAsync, but not after call to AcquireTokenSilentAsync

Tags: asp.net, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

So I have an application that's calling the graph API.

See the following snippet:
[image]

When the try (AquireTokenSilent) is called, the Web Request completes successfully no problem.

However, when make the same web request with the token I get from AcquireTokenAsync, I'm getting a 404 error and an exception thrown.

1) Can you recommend some good tools to analyze the HTTP request (so I can compare the difference and identify a problem). The Visual Studio debugger is helpful, but I can't see the whole picture, which obfuscates a possible problem here.

2) Can you help me identify why exactly one is successful and one fails? Both tokens seem to be acquired successfully, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: The Microsoft samples say you should just call a challenge to authenticate after the acquiretokensilent method throws the exception. However because await is called, HTTPContext is null, either by design or by bug.

So with that, I'm left with no option but to try to acquire the token manually. I think I'm pulling the token incorrectly, which is why the web request is failing. 

So how do I get the damn token properly?

Comment: I recommand that you could use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the http request. And then you could get the detail information about that.

Comment: I'm definitely going to use fiddler here, but I think the fundamental issue here is that this is a scenario where the authorization code hasn't been received, because the login token is from another session. 

I think I need to force a sign out in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured out what was the underlying cause here.

In our authentication scenario, we have multiple products using azure AD SSO in the ecosystem. Since 'OnAuthorizationCodeReceived' is only called on login, and NOT when a valid login cookie is already held, the token cache will not be populated with the authorization code. So in this case, the Microsoft code samples for this scenario are dead wrong. Issuing an authentication challenge wont cause 'OnAuthorizationCodeReceived' to be called, as you already hold a valid login token.

So, while it's a *litte* ugly, the fix is dead simple. Force a logout, so that the token cache can be populated.

```
          catch (AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException e)
        {
            //in this case, it's possible there's no authorization code because the login cookie is from another session in 
            //the ecosystem. So in this scenario, force a logout so we can get a token into the tokencache
            context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                                                                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            sessionState.Abandon();
        }
```

Now, because we're using this code outside the Controllers, and we call await, HttpContext will be null. Some serious voodoo going on in HttpContext, but I digress. We can use this little workaround to hang onto the context:

```
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var sessionState = context.Session;
```

EDIT: Came across one more problem when deploying the application to an azure app-service. You want to make sure Azure AD Authentication is toggle on in the 'Authentication' panel on Azure. We had some infinite login loop problems until I toggled this.

EDIT:
So, forcing a logout in this scenario really didn't sit well with me. BUT, I came across this question:

[Azure Active Directory Graph API - access token for signed in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949022/azure-active-directory-graph-api-access-token-for-signed-in-user)

And what we can do is follow the answer, and call AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(...), and make sure to use the 4 parameter method overload, where the last param is "https://graph.windows.net/"

Now, as long as we store the authorization code somewhere (in my case stored in a DB table). We should be able to get the authorization code for a given user, and get a new GraphAPI token, in the case where AcquireTokenSilentAsync(...) fails.

Now your statefull tokencache can be backed up by a stateless database call!

```
catch (AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException e)
            {

                //in this case, the stateful cache is empty, so lets get the codeId from the DB
                PersistentTokenCache pt = db.PersistentTokenCaches.Find(userObjectId);
                if (pt != null && pt.token != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = await ath.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(pt.token, 
                                                                                new Uri(Startup.hostUri),
                                                                                cc,
                                                                                "https://graph.windows.net");

                    }
                    catch (AdalException ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                        //both authentication types have failed
                        pt.token = null;
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                        context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                                                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                        sessionState.Abandon();
                        return -1;
                    }

                }
            }
```